# "Animated" text output

Tags: c, unix

How does text output that "animates" such as the unix command top work? I am not sure of the wording on this question, what I mean is that the output of top uses a fixed amount of space and the text changes as opposed to be appended

How can this be done in C? According to Wikipedia, top was written in C: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28software%29

Comment: Use the curses library http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29   (or ncurses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ed Heal has already pointed you to the ncurses library. This library allows you to create text windows in the console, where you can poistion the cursor.

The `ncurses` package is available on most Unix machines, but you may have to adjust your include and library paths.

Below is a very crude implementation of a clock. It uses `sleep` to control the animation.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>           /* for time and localtime */
#include <unistd.h>         /* for sleep */

#include <curses.h>         /* might need to adjust -Ipath */

const char *glyph[10] = {
    " OOOO OO  OOOO  OOOO  OOOO  OOOO  OO OOOO ",
    "  OO   OOO    OO    OO    OO    OO  OOOOOO",
    " OOOO OO  OO    OO   OO  OO   OO    OOOOOO",
    " OOOO OO  OO    OO  OOO     OOOO  OO OOOO ",
    "    OO   OOO  OOOOOO  OOOOOOOO    OO    OO",
    "OOOOOOOO    OOOOO     OO    OOOO  OO OOOO ",
    " OOOO OO  OOOO    OOOOO OO  OOOO  OO OOOO ",
    "OOOOOOOO  OO    OO   OO   OO    OO    OO  ",
    " OOOO OO  OOOO  OO OOOO OO  OOOO  OO OOOO ",
    " OOOO OO  OOOO  OO OOOOO    OOOO  OO OOOO "
};

void showtime(WINDOW *win)
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&now);

    int hh = tm->tm_hour;
    int mm = tm->tm_min;
    int ss = tm->tm_sec;
    int x;
    int i;

    x = (getmaxx(win) - 54) / 2;
    if (x < 0) x = 0;

    clear();
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        move(i + 2, x);
        printw("%.6s  %.6s      %.6s  %.6s      %.6s  %.6s",
            glyph[hh / 10] + 6*i, glyph[hh % 10] + 6*i,
            glyph[mm / 10] + 6*i, glyph[mm % 10] + 6*i,
            glyph[ss / 10] + 6*i, glyph[ss % 10] + 6*i);
    }

    refresh();    
}

int main()
{
    WINDOW *win = initscr();

    if (win == NULL) exit(1);
    noecho();               /* Don't echo unser input */
    nodelay(win, TRUE);     /* Don't wait for keypresses */

    for (;;) {
        int key;

        key = getch();
        if (key != ERR) break;

        showtime(win);
        sleep(1);
    }

    delwin(win);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I got it to work on a Mac as `gcc clock.c -o clock -i /usr/lib/libncurses.dylib`